# How to visualize impulse response function of exogenous variables in VAR? R

Tags: r, plot, visualization, var

Hello Stack community,

I am building the vector autoregression model with three endogenous and one exogenous variables. As I visualize impulse response functions (IRF) using the `irf()` function built for VAR package in R, it only plots IRFs with endogenous variables.

However, what I am interested in is the effect of exogenous variable on each endogenous variable, hence I need to plot IRF for exogenous variable.

I would greatly appreciate if someone has an idea how to obtain such plots? Is there a separate package for it? or if not the package, how else shall I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the package `MTS` has what you need:

Install it using `library("MTS")` and use the `VARXirf()` function:

```
VARXirf(model,lag=12,orth=TRUE)
```

[Link to the package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MTS/versions/1.0.3)